# How to edit a field having dynamically generated ID using WebDriver

Tags: webdriver

Below is the HTML code for the edit field.

```
<input class="inputField" id="CG.28443436.1.10.C.28443608.4.ATTATLD.28447933.DPSE.28447934.1.PSE.4974685.1.ATT.3115546.4.ATTRIBUTE" onmouseout="HideTextBoxValueinAltText()" onmousemove="DisplayTextBoxValueasAltText(this);" onfocus="closePopup(this.id);" onblur="enforceNumericEntry('','','',this.value,'Forward SCR/MCR', this, this.id,false);" type="text" size="30"/>
```

The ID is dynamically generated. Is there a way of identifying this object?

This is the text "Forward SCR/MCR" next to the edit field.

Comment: You can identify this element using [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) or [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). Or may be by className if it is unique.

Comment: Is the part of generated id `CG.` same everytime ?

Comment: yes, CG. is generated everytime

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selectors. So css below would read something like, *`"input of class name inputField which has id that starts with 'CG'"`*

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.inputField[id^='CG']"));
```

or

```
@FindBy(css="input.inputField[id^='CG']")
WebElement element
```

Update Based on the comment.

I would recommend you to talk to developers and request them for a unique attribute for elements so that you can use CSS selectors properly. Testability of application is important. That said, you always don't win such battles unfortunately. Been there done that!

`onBlur` is an event and not an attribute. I am not 100% sure if you could use CSS on an event. So here is a dirty hack you can do. Again, this is not recommended. Have a private method in your page that will return an input box based on its value. Looking at the DOM, this input box has an attribute `value` set to `Forward SCR/MCR`.

```
WebElement element = getInputElement(Forward SCR/MCR");

private WebElement getInputElement(String value) {
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input.inputField[id^='CG']"));
  for(WebElement element:elements) {
     if(element.getAttribute("value").equals(value))
       return element;
  }
  throw new RunTimeException("Couldn't find an element with value "+value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have multiple edit boxes (12) with the same html code except for the ID. Only the dynamically generated ID is the differentiater. Is there a way i can leverage on the java script - onblur="enforceNumericEntry('','','',this.value,'Forward SCR/MCR', this, this.id,false);"